# Factoring multiplicative group modulo n

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let  $\mathbb{Z}/{n}\mathbb{Z}$ be an additive group modulo n.
I know how to prove that $\mathbb{Z}/{mn}\mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z})$ for coprime $m, n$.

Let  $(\mathbb{Z}/{n}\mathbb{Z})^*$ be an multiplicative group modulo n. Does the statement above imply that $(\mathbb{Z}/{mn}\mathbb{Z})^* \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* \times (\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z})^*$?

In order to prove the first statement I could show that $ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z})$ is a cyclic group of order $mn$ but I can't do the same for multiplicative group. 
I tried to find some information about this and stumbled upon Chinese Remainder Theorem. Could this be proven without CRT since I don't know anything about it and I'm not yet ready to study it?

Comment: For arbitrary rings $R, R'$, try to find out what the unitgroup of $R \times R'$ is.

Comment: The first statement you wrote really *is* the Chinese remainder theorem, so that part you already know. If you have only seen it stated for the abelian groups, just check that the map given also respects multiplication.

Comment: It is not clear what your first statement means.  Before saying that two structures are isomorphic, you need to specify what structures you are talking about. Did you intend this to mean an isomorphism of additive groups or an isomorphism of rings?

Comment: You seem to be saying that you were talking about an isomorphism of additive groups. In that case the answer is no, an isomorphsim of additive groups implies nothing about the multiplicative structure of the objects in question. You would need to prove that they are isomorphic as rings (which isprecisely the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Note, a group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z /n \mathbb Z$ if and only if it contains an element of order $n$.

So, let this be a hint:

For the first statement, note we have $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$. Let $g_n$ and $h_m$ be generators of $\mathbb Z /n \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z /m \mathbb Z$ respectively. What is the order of $(g_n, h_m) \in \mathbb Z /n \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z /m \mathbb Z$ then?

Comment: Yes, I know that $(g_n, h_m) = (g_n, 1)(1,h_m)$ and since the orders of $(g_n, 1)$ and $(1, h_m)$ are coprime the order of their product is $mn$. I've edited the question and stated that I know a proof of this. The thing is I'd like to show the same for multiplicative group and this trick won't work. I guess I'll develop the full understanding of this when I learn about rings

Comment: @Atin Are you aware if $m|n$ then the homomorphism $\pi_m^n: \mathbb Z /n \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z /m \mathbb Z $ preserves multiplication?

Comment: Using coproducts in *Ab* you could then show (although I've yet to do this myself) that the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/{mn}\mathbb{Z} \to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z})$ perserves multiplication as well.